# Springboot, using security.basic.path property instead of custom WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, configuration

Using SpringBoot, I've activated SpringSecurity and initially I had created a custom WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${myapp.security.path.secured}")
    private String[] arraySecuredPaths;

    @Value("${api.root.path}")
    private String basePath;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(this.customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        String[] fullSecuredPaths = Arrays.stream(arraySecuredPaths).map(path -> basePath + path).toArray(String[]::new);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(fullSecuredPaths).authenticated().and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Then in my application.properties

```
api.root.path=/v1/myapi-name
myapp.security.path.secured=/mypath/pathsecured1,/mypath2,/mypath2/**
```

It works fine, cool.

My issue is, I thought that by using SpringBoot default property

```
security.basic.path=/v1/myapi-name/mypath/pathsecured1,/v1/myapi-name/mypath2,/v1/myapi-name/mypath2/**
```

I could remove all the code inside SecurityConfiguration and its inheritance:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {}
```

But if I do that ALL paths are not getting secured instead of just the defined one.

What I'm missing?

Comment: Because your `@EnableWebSecurity` disables the auto configuration of spring security.

Comment: Oh missed that one thanks.
So after removing it, I'm guessing I'll have to add `security.basic.enabled=true` to enable security right ?

Comment: It should be enabled by default when Spring Security is detected.

Comment: Indeed, thank you.
I have fiddled a bit with it but I guess I'm out of luck since I need to declre somewhere that the authenticationProvider is my custom customAuthenticationProvider bean. If there is a way to just declare that without having to write all the java configuration as well ?